# Custom shortcut keys to .lnk files doesn't work anymore in Windows 11

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, shortcuts

I have created a custom shortcut key (in a .lnk file) for a folder directory, and it was working fine for a while. But it suddenly stopped working today when I tried to use the shortcut key. I have set the shortcut key as CTRL + SHIFT + D. The shortcut file (.lnk) points to the correct path of the executable and is placed on the dekstop. I have used cmd commands to hide the .lnk file with `attrib +h +s +r filename.lnk`. I tried removing the shortcut key and re-assigning the hotkey, but that didn't work either. Not sure why the shortcut stopped working suddenly. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Windows updates have restricted the folders where a shortcut (.lnk file) can be accessed by a *keyboard* shortcut. For example, try putting the .lnk in the folder below, and then setting a different keyboard shortcut (since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> may now be unavailable).

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\`

If that does not work, then try repairing the OS with [DISM and SFC](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image).

Finally, since Microsoft *does* tend to make arbitrary changes in the Desktop, Start Menu and other GUI features, consider a third-party utility to manage **all** your own keyboard shortcuts in one place, such as [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/). These tools have the advantages of showing all user hotkeys and of not being subject to change at the next Windows update.

Comment: It worked! I hope it stays working after a few weeks. Thank you for the help.