# Switch Windows 10 default browser with hotkeys

Tags: windows-10, browser

I have Firefox for my personal use and Chrome for work. Is it possible to setup some hotkeys to switch between them as default system browser? If it's possible to add a popup window, that would be really cool.

Comment: What you are looking for isn’t built-into Windows. You would have to author your own application to support what you describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* create two .reg scripts to set either browser as default, but  it would take longer to select the script and go through the UAC dialog than to use the *Default apps* control panel.

However, you *can* make a shortcut link to that CPL, and then assign the link a keyboard shortut

- Right-click the Desktop or a folder.
- Select *New > Shortcut*
- For the location of the item, enter `ms-settings:defaultapps` .
- Name the shortcut as you wish.
- *Finish* (saves the shortcut .lnk).
- Right-click the shortcut, select *Properties*, and add a *Shortcut key* combo, if you wish.

**N.B.** Keyboard shortcuts might only work if the .lnk is [kept in specific folders](https://superuser.com/questions/1786297/custom-shortcut-keys-to-lnk-files-doesnt-work-anymore-in-windows-11).